# Return 4 separate counts for single column in SSRS DataSet

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to provide 5 counts to SSRS from a conditional count on a column.  For instance, suppose the column held the color of a product -- green ,blue, red and yellow.  What I would like to do is return the count of each in a single query.

Although I can accomplish getting this done using a case statement:

```
Select
      COUNT(*) 'Count',
      case
            When Color = 'BL' then 'Blue
            When Color = 'RD' then 'Red
            When Color = 'YL' then 'Yellow
            When Color = 'GR' then 'Green
            Else 'All Others'
      End as Payment
From COLORS(NoLock)
Group by
      case
            When Color = 'BL' then 'Blue
            When Color = 'RD' then 'Red
            When Color = 'YL' then 'Yellow
            When Color = 'GRthen ‘Green’
            Else 'All Others'
      End
```

When I use the dataset is SSRS, all I get is the a single count.  I don't want to create 4 dataset queries as I'm actually selection the records by the parameters start and end date and I would end up having 5 sets of date parameters.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also, unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I am not sure what seems to be the issue here, I just tested this query in SSRS and it produced 5 rows of data, one for each of the `colors` and then the `all others` value.  Can you clarify what you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
select count (*) as Total,
   sum (case when color='BL' then 1 else 0 end) as BlueTotal,
   sum (case when color='RD' then 1 else 0 end) as RedTotal,
   sum (case when color='YL' then 1 else 0 end) as YellowTotal,
   sum (case when color='GR' then 1 else 0 end) as GreenTotal
from Colors
```